# Adding three dots or the ellipsis character to regex which targets the end of sentences

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
 $text = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+\.\d+|\b[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?)|([.,;:!?)])\s*/', function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1] ? $matches[1] : $matches[2] . ' ';
    }, $text);
```

Which targets the end of sentences and avoids abbreviations like `N.B.C.`

It works fine. The problem is that it doesn't detect tree dots `...` or the ellipsis symbol `…` as the end of the sentence.

How can I adjust the regex to include it as well?

Comment: Please provide example of source string and desired result

Comment: It's a good idea to add a descriptive title to your question, which will let anyone get the idea what this question is about

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a space after one of the punctuations, but not for the digits or the abbreviations and then only after 1 or 3 dots, you could make use of SKIP FAIL and `\K`

In the replacement you could then use a space and use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)+\b|[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:[,;:!?…]+(?=[^\s,;:!?…])|(?<!\.)(?:\.{3}|\.)(?=[^\s.]))\K
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)+\b` Match 1+ digits and repeat 1+ times `.` and 1+ digits followed by a word boundary
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?` Match a single char A-Z and optionally repeat `.` and a char A-Z and an optional dot
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skip the match
- `|` Or
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[,;:!?…]+(?=[^\s,;:!?…])` Match 1+ times any of the listed characters, and assert that to the right there is a non whitespace char except being one of the listed characters
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<!\.)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a dot directly to the elft
  - `(?:\.{3}|\.)` Match either 3 or 1 dots
  - `(?=[^\s.])` Positive lookahead, assert a non whitespace char to the right, except for a dot
    -`)` Close the non capture group
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KDhnvn/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Nhjec)

For example

```
$pattern = '/\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)+|[A-Z](?:\.[A-Z])*\b\.?)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:[,;:!?…]+(?=[^\s,;:!?…])|(?<!\.)(?:\.{3}|\.)(?=[^\s.]))\K/u';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, " ", $string);
```

Comment: If you write `[,;:!?…]+(?=[^\s,;:!?…])` without the u modifier or without starting with `(*UTF)`, you will cut all multi-byte characters (from U+2000 to U+2FFF) that start with the byte E2 (the first byte of the ellipsis character): https://3v4l.org/Nsk2M#v8.2.9